# css/jquery scroll-fixed div issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fix a div after a certain pixels when the window's browser scrolls down and after, when the window scrolls up, put the div in the same position at the beginning.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var button = $('.button-mobile');
    offset = button.offset().top;
    position = button.position().top;
    console.log(position);
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= offset) {
        $('.button-mobile').css({
            "max-height": "100%",
            "position": "fixed",
            "overflow-y": "auto",
            "top": "40px",
            "z-index": "1"
        });
    } else {
        $('.button-mobile').css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": "none",
            "overflow-y": "none",
            "z-index": "none"
        });
    }
});
```

The `if` branch works well.
The `else` branch is the problem, I think.

This branch is a test for a precedent experiment. `else` branch works with known height in px but not with the offset that change frequently.

Also I don't know why when the window scroll down to the div the position's top value is set to 40px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should move **button** and **offset** assignment out of scroll callback:

```
    var button = $('.button-mobile');
    var offset = button.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        position = button.position().top;
        console.log(position);
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= offset) {
            $('.button-mobile').css({
                "max-height": "100%",
                "position": "fixed",
                "overflow-y": "auto",
                "top": "40px",
                "z-index": "1"
            });
        } else {
            $('.button-mobile').css({
                "position": "static",
                "top": "none",
                "overflow-y": "none",
                "z-index": "none"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, now it's ok

Comment: I am glad to help.By the way, you can replace **$('.button-mobile')** with **button** inside callback function to avoid unnecessary DOM search when scrolling.